# What does "philoso-fugal" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "philoso-fugal" mean in the following sentence?

> It seems to me that a consideration of Malick’s art demands that we take seriously the idea that film is less an illustration of philosophical ideas and theories—let’s call that a philoso-fugal reading—and more a form of philosophizing, of reflection, reasoning, and argument.
>   <sub>[Simon Critchley, 'Calm — On Terrence Malick's *The Thin Red Line*'](https://books.google.com/books?id=usmTAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq="It+seems+to+me+that+a+consideration+of+Malick%E2%80%99s+art")</sub>

Comment: Seems to be a mix of _philosophical_ and _centrifugal_. No idea what that mixture is supposed to mean, though. Perhaps something that revolves around philosophy? Or maybe something about putting philosophy in the washing machine on the spin cycle?

Comment: A fugue is a strictly-organised contrapuntal composition.  Critchley here is suggesting 'philoso-fugal' as a term to describe a mistaken, in Critchley's view, way of understanding Malik's approach and intent (overly categorical; insufficiently free and rhapsodic).

Answer (score 1):

The text is difficult to understand fully, but it appears to be a portmanteau of *philosophical* and *fugal*

> **fugal**
>
> : of, relating to, or being in the style of a musical fugue

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fugal

> **fugue**
>
> 1 a : a musical composition in which one or two themes are repeated or imitated by successively entering voices and contrapuntally developed in a continuous interweaving of the voice parts
>
> b : something that resembles a fugue especially in interweaving repetitive elements
>
> 2 : a disturbed state of consciousness in which the one affected seems to perform acts in full awareness but upon recovery cannot recollect the acts performed

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fugue

That leaves us with two possibilities: either this kind of film analysis is repetitive and contrapuntal and interwoven, or else it resembles a fugue state. Neither meaning obviously fits, but either one seems possible.

---

In case anyone else wants to take a stab at a broader analysis, the quotation comes from here: ["Calm - On Terrence Malick's *The Thin Red Line*"](https://www.euppublishing.com/doi/full/10.3366/film.2002.0023)